# Launcher for a Python program that requires extra libraries

Tags: gnome3, python, path, cd-command

I'm trying to get a launcher working for the WikidPad (python) program.
I already have a python program, so I looked into the file `/usr/share/applications/taskcoach.desktop`. The exec line was simply `taskcoach.py`.

But I cannot start WikidPad just typing "WikidPad.py", I have to write `python WikidPad.py`, then it starts correctly from the command line.

So I made the `.desktop file` for wikidpad, in the exec line I wrote `python /home/abc/wikidpad/WikidPad.py`.

But it seems that you have to be in the same directory in order to get correct results, otherwise there is the error `No module named pwiki.Enum`.

So I changed the exec line into `cd /home/abc/wikidpad;python WikidPad.py`.

But that did also not work, the error message was `cd could not be executed, file or directory not found`.

If I want to execute a Linux command in a bash script and I get an error "command/file not found", I adjust the PATH variable or write the full path of the command. That normally helps.

But in this case, `cd` is a built in bash command, and I cannot write `whereis cd` in order to get the full path of the command.

I do not have any idea to get this going.

Answer (score 2):

The *Exec* key in a `.desktop` file [accepts](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html) only one executable name (+ arguments):

> The *Exec* key must contain a command line. A command line consists of an executable program optionally followed by one or more arguments.

So, you either:

- invoke the shell with an explicit `sh -c "command_string"` (where `command_string` = your actual commands):

  ```
  Exec=sh -c "cd /home/abc/wikidpad; python WikidPad.py"
  ```

or

- put your commands in a script (somewhere in your `$PATH`), make it executable and have the `.desktop` file execute the script:

  ```
  Exec=my_script
  ```

  (or `Exec=/full/path/to/my_script` if the script is not in your `$PATH`).

Answer (score 1):

It depends a bit on where the `pwiki` directory is (or a `pwiki.py` file), but assuming it is in `/home/abc/wikidpad/` you can add the following to `/home/abc/wikidpad/WikidPad.py` **before** the the import of `pwiki.Enum`:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/abc/wikidpad')
```

(Replacing the directory with the directory where you found `pwiki`)